# Chrome disabled key remapped with xkb

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, keyboard-layout, xkb

I remapped my PageUp and PageDown keys since they were awkwardly placed right above the left and right keys (XPS13 2018).
To do so, I changed the file called 'pc' in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols. More specifically, I replaced the lines

key  {    [  Prior    ]   };

key  {    [  Next     ]   };

by

key  {    [  NoSymbol, Prior      ]   };

key  {    [  NoSymbol, Next       ]   };

and then restarted X server.

With these settings, hitting the PgUp key for example isn't supposed to do anything, and hitting Shift+PgUp should excute the regular PgUp action (same with PgDown).

This seemed to solve my issue: in all applications like terminal, text editors, other gtk apps, the keys are mapped to the right actions.

My only issue concerns Google Chrome; Shift+Pgup doesn't do anything, neither does PgUp (same with PgDown). These keys seems to now be useless on Chrome.

Is their a way for remapping a key (PgUp/PgDown) so it is not assigned to anything if hit normally, and to execute its normal behavior if doing Shift+key (or Ctrl+key/Altgr+key etc.), for both the system and other apps like Chrome?

P.S.: I tried remapping keys using xmodmap. This worked for the terminal and text editors but not on Chrome and a couple of other GTK apps; these latter seem to ignore the mappings, and execute the normal actions for these keys.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on X server (and not wayland).

Comment: When you press [shift]+[PgUp], the application will receive both key events. Additionally, the application can look up the keysym mapping. It is completely up to the (developer of the) application how to handle the key events. Chrome, for example, does nothing because there is no action bound to [shift]+[PgUp]. I'm going to write an answer and provide a workaround later.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I am looking forward to seeing your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the shift key is still a modifier, so even though pressing PgUp generates no event, pressing Shift + PgUp generates a Shift + PgUp event.  With this set up, there is no way to generate a plain PgUp keypress which is likely what Chrome wants.

The only way around this is to change the Shift key so that it is not a modifier but instead selects an overlay.  This is similar to how AltGr works, where AltGr + 4 emits a Euro currency symbol on some key layouts without it looking like Alt is being pressed at the same time.

You probably wouldn't want to do this with Shift (since you'd then lose the other functionality associated with the Shift key) however you can pick another key for it.  I used the Caps Lock key on my key layout to switch between groups, in my case so that some letter keys behave normally but when I hold Caps, those letter keys turn into arrow keys for cursor navigation.